# Creating a slow information feed

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I currently have a div on my website that fades in and out every 6 seconds or so with different information. Now previously I just hard coded in the separate divs then just made them fade in and out of each other.

But that seems of a bit of a sloppy way of doing it especially as the data will be constantly updated, therefore I have made a XML document which I can easily update how and when I like.

The problem I am facing is that I am unsure on how to use jQuery to load the XML document -> select first  -> wait 6 seconds -> load second item?

So far I have this.

```
function load_news(){
    $(".news").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url:'news.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).find('news item').each(function() {
                var news = $(this).find("body").text();
                var news_img = $(this).find("img").text();
                $(".news").append("<div class='news'><div class='wrap'><div class='glare'></div><img src='img/news/"+news_img+".jpg'/><div class='name'>"+news+"</div></div></div>");
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Did not Find XML file");
        }
    });
}
```

But as you can see I am stuck on how to make it loop through the data received?

Comment: setInterval(code,millisec,lang) - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: I don't see how that would restrict the xml data to show one at a time?

Comment: What server side language are you using? or is this straight html?

Comment: PHP But it needs to be done in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Separate these two processes.

Make one that has a queue of items to display. Based on the timer, just show the next item. If the Queue is empty, just try again after the timeout.

Make another function that periodically fills up the queue by fetching new data - get all of the available data each time.

Comment: But how would it know what to ignore if it is trying to find new data?

Comment: Depends on the data you get. You could count the number of items and skip the old ones, or if there is a unique ID, keep track of what's already in your queue.

Comment: Could you give an example. I'm feeling very confused right now.